# Sympy submodule membership not accounting for inverses in the ring?

Tags: python, module, sympy, algebra

When I run the following code

```
from sympy import Symbol,GF
x=Symbol("x")
ring = GF(2).old_poly_ring(x,x**-1)
print(ring)
print([0,1/x] in ring.free_module(2).submodule([0, x]))
print([0,1] in ring.free_module(2).submodule([0, x]))
print([0,x**3] in ring.free_module(2).submodule([0, x]))
```

I get the following output:

```
GF(2)[x,1/x]
False
False
True
```

Which does not seem correct to me.

My understanding is that a submodule of the free module over a ring R, generated by vector f, is the set of all vectors v = r f where r is in R.

If I consider the submodule generated by f=[0,x], with my ring being R=GF(2)[x, 1/x], then I would expect that [0, 1]= (1/x)f is in my submodule. Similarly for [0,1/x] = (1/x)^2 f. Given that [0, x^3] is in the submodule, it somehow seems like sympy is only considering a part of the ring... what am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure that `old_poly_ring` has any notion that `x` and `1/x` are related. I think it's just treating `1/x` as if it were a completely separate symbol like `y`. If you replace `1/x` everywhere with `y` then does the output make more sense?

Comment: That's very helpful! Indeed if one were to replace 1/x with a new symbol y, then those outputs would make sense. In fact I think I have found a hack that should replicate the functionality I would like.

If I define my ring by a quotient, with y acting as the inverse of x, then  [0,y] is in ring.free_module(2).submodule([0, x]))

But this seems suboptimal. Does anyone know of a more straightforward way of representing the ring of laurent polynomials?

Comment: I don't think SymPy has anything that is explicitly intended to support Laurent polynomials.